# Django: Adding social authentication to site

Tags: python, django, social-authentication

I'm a beginner in Django and I'm studying Django from the book **"Django 2 by Example"**, written by Antonio Mele. I'm trying to **add social authentication to my site**(book page no. 251) {*project name-bookmark, app name-account*}. Up to this point, I'm installed the Django package

> "social-auth-app-django",

synced python-social-auth models with database using migration and added "social_django" to the INSTALLED_APPS settings of my project. Then I've added

> path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),

now it is telling me to edit my hosts file located at "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" and to add "127.0.0.1 mysite.com" line which I've added. After this running server "http://example.com:8000/account/login/" should give error, *here example.com is actually mysite.com*,

> DisallowedHost at /account/login:
>   Invalid HTTP_HOST header:'mysite.com:8000'.You may need to add 'mysite.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

But I don't know why it isn't showing instead of that it gives me "This site can’t be reached. mysite.com refused to connect."

But it works perfectly fine at 127.0.0.1:8000.
Please help me I'm stuck. I've searched on google as well as watched videos on youtube but still, this error can't be solved(generated) by me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `hosts` file in your `etc` folder.

Don't add the `#` on the line that contains your new line adding `mysite.com`